# upload file with a form via ajax nodejs express

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

this is the ajax file

```
$(form).submit(function()
            {
                $.ajax(
                {
                    url:'/newProduct',
                    cache: false,
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: $(form).serialize(),
                    success:function(datos)
                    {
                        console.dir(datos)
                    },
                    error:function(xhr,tm)
                    {

                    },
                    complete:function()
                    {
                        form.reset();

                    }
                })
return false        

            });
```

this on the server

```
exports.newProduct=function(req,res)
{
    console.dir(req.body)
    console.dir(req.files)
    return res.send('Producto Cargado correctamente.');
}
```

the file didnt upload, the info on server shows nothing, nothing happends

Comment: "exports.newProduct" where are you adding this route to express?

Comment: app.post('/newProduct',routes.newProduct);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't (as far as I understand it) use `$.ajax` to perform a *multipart/form-data* form submission (not without manually building the POST body). The Express file upload requires that your HTML `<form>` element have the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute set. Do you have it set?

For what you're trying to do you probably want to use a hidden iframe to perform the post, then have the server return a javascript snippet that calls back with success/failure. There are a number of jQuery plugins that do this for you ([jQuery Form](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/) does it, I believe).

Comment: i set in form enctype="multipart/form-data", and in ajax but have an error in server

Answer (score 1):

only with html5 formData object and you need to append files to it manually:

[New Tricks in XMLHttpRequest2](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/)

[uploading files with ajax](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/uploading-files-with-ajax/)

you can use jQuery nice plugin like with fallback etc.:

[jQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/)

Comment: yes you can, with `window.formData` and it is supported by latest browsers. posing with iframe is an old hack. i recommend you to read a bit with the links i posted.