# Not Able To Get The Image Uploaded To Node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

**Client Side Code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var fileSelected;
  console.log("Document Loaded");
  $('#userPhotoInput').on('change', function(e){
      fileSelected = e.target.files[0];  
      console.log(fileSelected.name);   
  });

  $('#uploadForm').submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log("Submit Clicked");
      $.ajax({
          type:'POST',
          url :'/upload',
          processData: false,
          contentType: false,
          beforeSend: function(request) {
              request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", fileSelected.type);
          }
          success : function(data){
              console.log(data);
          },
          error : function(error){
              console.log(error)
          }
      });
      return false;
  });
});
```

**Server Side**

```
// Global app configuration section
app.set('views', 'cloud/views');  // Specify the folder to find templates
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');    // Set the template engine
app.use(express.bodyParser());    // Middleware for reading request body
app.post('/upload',function(req,res){
    var response = "";
    for(var key in req){
        console.log(key);
    response += ((!response.length) ? "" : ",") + key;
    }
    res.send(response.split(","));
});
```

The content length I'm getting it on server, which is well and good. But unable to get the data from the request. I try to get the req.files but there is no property like this in the request. Also req.body is returning an empty Object. Can Any one guid me on this ?

**Server Log**

```
Input: {"method"=>"POST", "url"=>"/upload", "headers"=>{"version"=>"HTTP/1.1", "host"=>"myhost", "user-agent"=>"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36", "content-length"=>"2348", "accept"=>"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8", "accept-encoding"=>"gzip,deflate,sdch", "accept-language"=>"en-US,en;q=0.8,ar;q=0.6", "cache-control"=>"max-age=0", "content-type"=>"multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryHsBgtmA9Sojnhbpx"}}
```

Comment: can you also log the headers and check if content-type is properly selected?

Comment: I have appended the server log

Comment: add `app.use(express.bodyParser());` in your server code. You can then access `req.files`

Comment: But those things are already present in my code.

Answer (score 0):

The html doc & form you are using is not available... but the issue is with `Ajax upload`.

Normally `file upload will cause a page refresh`, if you like to do the upload async you would need to ...

1. Use iframes(a bit boring now .. ).
2. Use Jquery plugins(client side plugins) that are available.

Previous stackoverflow answer - [upload file with a form via ajax nodejs express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17015349/upload-file-with-a-form-via-ajax-nodejs-express)

This link demonstrates ajax file upload using a plugin `trickery` - http://markdawson.tumblr.com/post/18359176420/asynchronous-file-uploading-using-express-and-node-js

Comment: Un fortunately I'm using Parse.com as back end and this solution did not came right. Instead I have created the base64 string of the file and uploaded it and it did worked.